# python average test score

Tags: python, while-loop, average

Im trying to write a program that will determine the average of a number tests. The number of tests will vary, but I do not want it to be initially set by user input. I'm want to use a while loop and a sentinel value of zero to stop the input. I would like the average to display to three decimal places, with the % symbol immediately following the final digit as shown below...
SAMPLE RUN:
Enter test score 80
Enter test score 70
Enter test score 90
Enter test score 88
Enter test score 0
The average is 82.000%

```
total =0
counter = 0

while True:
    entry = int(input('Enter test score:'))
    if entry ==0:
        break

    total += entry
    counter += 1
    average = (total/counter)

 print("The average score:",format(average, '.3f'),'%',sep='')
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: @AlexHall I'm using python 3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
total = 0
counter = 0

while True:
    entry = int(input("Enter Test score: "))
    if entry == 0: break
    total += entry   # this should be in while loop
    counter += 1

total = total * 1.0
if counter == 0: exit(1)
avg = total / counter
print("Average is: %3.f" % avg + '%')
```

total += entry should be inside while loop, because you want to add it for every entry received.
hope that helped :)

Comment: if I have my print line like this print("The average score:",format(average, '.3f'))    where would my percent sign go?

Comment: use format like `print( "The average score: {0}%".format(avg) )`   . Percent sign was not in output because it was not present in string.. arguments of format are replaced in string in that order. You might want to adjust precision before printing like that: use `round(avg[, 3]`

Answer (score 1):

`While` needs to be all lowercase.

`if entry == 0` is missing a colon.

`total += entry` and `counter += 1` need to be inside the loop since they must happen with every iteration.

Did you try running the code you had before posting here?

Comment: it came back with an error... saying I had not defined true...but I wasn't even sure if this is the proper way to get the result I was trying for... @alexhall

Comment: Use `True`, but also you didn't even mention `true` anywhere in your code. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you even tried, because your code as is in not able to run at all. However, here is the answer.  You'll want to store the results in a list, then get the average by the sum of the list over the length of the list (number of scores).  the .format method allows you to specify 3 decimal places.

```
scores = []
while True:
    entry = int(input('Enter test score: '))
    if entry == 0:
       break 
    scores.append(entry)


print('The average is', "{0:.3f}".format(float(sum(scores) / len(scores))))
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.

```
scores = []
while True:
    entry = input("Enter test score: ")
    if entry == '':
        break
    elif not entry.isnumeric():
        print("Scores must be numeric.")
    else:
        scores.append(int(entry))

average = sum(scores)/len(scores)
print("The average score is {:.03f}.".format(average))
```

The average is computed by taking the sum of the list of `scores` and dividing it by the total number of elements in `scores`. The rest is just logic to ensure that the user inputs numeric scores and exit when the user enters nothing (just presses <kbd>Return</kbd> with no text).

Comment: how would I add the percent sign to my current print line with out any spaces between the last number and the symbol?

Comment: @CzSzPzTz: Add it right before the period. `print("The average score is {:.03f}%.".format(average))`

Answer (score 0):

```
total =0
counter = 0

while True:
    entry = int(input('Enter test score:'))
    if entry ==0:
        break

total += entry
counter += 1
average = (total/counter)

print("The average score:",format(average, '.3f'),'%',sep='')
```